# Can I programmatically determine if an Airflow DAG was parsed or triggered?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Can I programmatically determine if an Airflow DAG was parsed or triggered?

Case: I need to call a python library outside of any DAG tasks to make some env preparations before tasks run.

Problem: I do need it to be run only when the DAG is triggered (at RUNtime), but not at PARSE time (every 30 seconds).

Thanks!

Googled a solution but nothing similar found...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a new documented solution:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/dynamic-dag-generation.html - see Optimizing DAG parsing delays during execution section (end of page), New in version 2.4.

Example of the code in DAG body outside any task definition:

```
#In case “full” parsing is needed (for example in DAG File Processor), dag_id and task_id of the context are set to None. 
if get_parsing_context().dag_id is not None:   
    your runtime-only code to be NOT executed at DAG import time goes here  
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little more context, we could help you better but in this case,
The `ExternalTaskSensor` could helps
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create an EmptyOperator at the begging of the dag and define its
on_execute_callback

```
def start_dag(context):
   ...

start_task=EmptyOperator(task_id="start", on_execute_callback=start_dag)
```

Comment: but this is an equivalent of using a separate PythonOperator, isn't it?
And the PythonOperator callable doesn't work OR isn't executed the same way / with same context as the code outside tasks is run.

Comment: its without the python_callable function that you need to supply . and in some providers (like astronomer) empty operators are not countable in the tasks program (way to measure your cost) cause it doesn't consume resources.

Comment: It looks like there is a new documented solution:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/dynamic-dag-generation.html
- see Optimizing DAG parsing delays during execution section (end of page), New in version 2.4.

Example of the code in DAG body outside any task definition:

`#In case “full” parsing is needed (for example in DAG File Processor), dag_id and task_id of the context are set to None.
if get_parsing_context().dag_id is not None: 
   your runtime-only code to be NOT executed at DAG import time goes here
`
....